# How can i leave hover state for some time with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout, show-hide

I have this situation: my menu li have some hidden elements, after i hover it this elements is showing. Eveything is fine, i have some timeouts etc. but when i leave hovered element my submenu hides to. I'v set this timeouts becouse i don't want to this submenus hide after change every main menu element, end if i am on 'timeout area' i can get to submenus. Problems starts when i'm mouse out of main menu element, timeout works but after this interval my submenu hide. How can i leave submenu visible when i'm on 'timeout area'? I hope that is clear explenation...

[image]

and my code:

```
$('.main_menu ul li').hover(function() {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(self).children('.sub_menu_main').addClass('opened');
    }, 200);
}, function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.main_menu ul li').children('.sub_menu_main').removeClass('opened');
    }, 200);
});
```

or, this works to:

```
var main_menu_element = $('.main_menu ul li');
main_menu_element.on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        var self = this,
            time = 500;
        $(self).data('timer', setTimeout(function(){
            $(self).children('.sub_menu_main').addClass('opened');
        }, time));
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        var self = this,
            time = 500;
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(self).children('.sub_menu_main').removeClass('opened');
        }, time);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a variable to the setTimeout function, then clear the timeout if the user hovers back over.

```
var t1;
$('.main_menu ul li').hover(function() {
    clearTimeout(t1);
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(self).children('.sub_menu_main').addClass('opened');
    }, 200);
}, function() {
    t1 = setTimeout(function() {
        $('.main_menu ul li').children('.sub_menu_main').removeClass('opened');
    }, 200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If display is applied on `open` class that is what your code does.
No surprises here see it yourself http://jsfiddle.net/7GWKX/. Maybe something in your concept is messed up.

Is that what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/7GWKX/15/

```
$('.main_menu ul li').hover(function (e) {
    var self = this,
        time = (e.type ==='mouseleave') ? 1000 : 200;
    var t = setTimeout(function () {
        hoverCallback(self);
    }, time);
});

function hoverCallback(parentNode) {
    $('.sub_menu_main',parentNode).toggleClass('opened');
};
```